# double integrals when $R$ is the right half of the unit circle

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $R$ be the right half of the unit circle. Evaluate in terms of $\,\,dxdy$.

$$\iint_R xy^2\, dA$$

The first integral should be from $-1$ to $1$ and the second on $-\sqrt{1-y^2}$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$.

I have noticed that $x$ is an odd function so its integral is $0$.

I cannot seem to get the correct answer which is $\frac{2}{15}$.

I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're suggesting corresponds to integrating over the *top* half of the unit circle. For the right half you need $$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y^2x\; dy\;dx.$$

**Edit**

Looking at Siong Thye Goh's answer and back at yours I realize that you said the y-integral integral was from $-1$ to $1,$ not $0$ to $1,$ so you weren't integrating over the top half of the disk, but rather over the whole disk. Either of our modifications will get you to the right answer. At first pass, his looks like it'll be easier.

**Edit II**

Here is how the calculation goes. My way: $$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y^2x\; dy\;dx.\\= \frac{2}{3}\int_0^1(1-x^2)^{3/2}x\;dx \\=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1u^{3/2}\;du = \frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{5} = \frac{2}{15}$$
where we subbed $u=1-x^2.$

Siong Thye Goh's way:

$$
\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} y^2x\;dx\;dy\\=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1y^2(1-y^2)dy = \frac{1}{2}2\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right) = \frac{2}{15}.
$$

Comment: This way gets $2/15...$ the inner integral is over $y$ and thus is not zero.

Comment: yes yes yes terribly sorry! I go it now thank you so much

Comment: @Flow no problem... went overboard and wrote out the whole thing.

Comment: Extremely grateful for that. Once again thank you very much for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

If your inner integral is with respect to $x$, the right integral should be $$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{\color{red}0}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} xy^2\, dx \, dy$$

Notice that we are integrating from $0$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ rather than $-\sqrt{1-y^2}$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ because $R$ is the right half of the unit circle.

Notice that we don't get to use the property that $x$ is an odd function.